# Robot Test execution error in Firefox browser - WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I get the following error while trying to execute my Robot tests in Firefox V 42.0:

**WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: c:\users\ic020092\appdata\local\temp\tmphwcokh\webdriver-py-profilecopy**

Configuration details:
Selenium V 2.53
Python V 2.7.3
Robot Framework 3.0
Firefox V 42.0

I've tried executing the same tests in Chrome and it works fine.
I tried looking up this error in various forums and tried the solutions given as well, such as *pip install -U selenium* and trying to execute with other lower/higher firefox versions. No luck!

Comment: How do you open the browser in your test script? Do you use `Open Browser` keyword. If so, which arguments do you set?

Comment: Yes I use Open browser keyword with ${URL} and ${BROWSER} variables. But my default browser is Chrome so I pass Firefox in my command line arguments the following way:
pybot --variable BROWSER: Firefox Testname.txt